# Bind9 Name Server slave having master file transfer problems

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I have a master name server set up and now I am trying to configure the slave. Bind9 appears to load and run fine, however I am getting the following error:

```
Apr 27 12:47:21 ns2 named[23563]: dumping master file: slaves/tmp-oJ5LJ1RtO4: open: file not found
```

Here is my named.conf.options file:

```
options {

recursion yes;
allow-recursion { trusted; };
listen-on { 10.0.1.11; }; //this machines IP. 
allow-transfer { none; };

// If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
// to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
// ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

// If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
// nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
// Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
// the all-0's placeholder.

forwarders {
    10.0.1.12;
    x.x.x.x; //keeping my ISPs nameservers private for post in askUbunutu
    x.x.x.x; //
};

//========================================================================
// If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
// you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
//========================================================================
dnssec-validation auto;

auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; };
```

};

Slaves named.conf.local file:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
zone "mycity.example.com" {
type slave;
file "slaves/db.mycity.example.com";
masters { 10.0.1.12; };
};

zone "1.0.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type slave;
    file "slaves/db.10";
    masters { 10.0.1.12; };
};
```

Directory permissions for /etc/bind/slaves

```
drwxr-sr-x   2 bind bind  4096 Apr 27 09:41 slaves
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file directive is relative to the bind var directory on ubuntu that defaults to the following:

/var/cache/bind

That is unless changed using the directory directive in options, thus it is looking for the following directory to save the data:

/var/cache/bind/slaves

Note this is probably a better location anyway really it's not ideal to give bind write access to it's own /etc directory since doing so allows someone to potentially alter your bind configuration if they somehow exploit bind safer to keep variable data somewhere else and let the server write there.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I will try that but what should the permissions be for the slaves directory?

Comment: Getting this error now: dumping master file: slaves/tmp-TI8XpgptmN: open: file not found ... with these permissions: drwxr-xr-x  2 root bind     4096 Apr 27 14:25 slaves

Comment: The permissions you have will be fine just place it under /var/cache/bind instead personally just find it good practice not to have deamons having write access to their own configuration directory or a subpath of it.

Comment: Should it be bind:bind for permissions? That shouldnt matter right? Also, why is it still saying file not found?. Ok I changed permissions to bind:bind and its still not working ;'(

Comment: It's because the slaves directory is not being found at /var/cache/bind/slaves thus it can't create the temporary file at /var/cache/bind/slaves/tmp-xxxxxxxxxx to store the transferred zone. Bind first creates a temporary file in the same directory then copies it to the defined filename from the config only after the transfer is completed stops it losing data if the transfer fails partway.

Comment: I have created it there but its still not working: /var/cache/bind/slaves

Comment: Ok I solved it. I was also missing the following in the named.conf.options file: directory "/var/cache/bind";